# Windows 11 Start button and search menus unresponsive

Tags: search, windows-11, start-menu, windows-search, start

Earlier, my taskbar was blank with no icons, Start menu or search bar.
I went into regedit, to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell\Update\Packages, created UndockingDisabled, and set it to 1.  Upon refreshing Explorer, everything reappeared (except the date and time)...but the Start menu and search bar are completely unresponsive.

I've Googled and tried all of the usual fixes, including restarting Explorer, re-registering StartMenuExperienceHost.exe, etc., but none of those methods have worked.

I checked the Event Viewer and am seeing the following:

```
Faulting application name: StartMenuExperienceHost.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x36fcc2bb
Faulting module name: StartDocked.dll, version: 10.0.22000.856, time stamp: 0x24763eff
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x00000000001972f7
Faulting process id: 0x1590
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8ad30b26fd9a3
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\StartMenuExperienceHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\StartDocked.dll
Report Id: ecb91fd2-6f88-4dc3-82a2-78ce645e29e5
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_10.0.22000.778_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

I then set UndockingDisabled to 0, whereupon the whole taskbar went blank again, and I saw the following in the Event Viewer:

```
Faulting application name: SearchHost.exe, version: 421.22500.4025.0, time stamp: 0x62a3861b
Faulting module name: combase.dll, version: 10.0.22000.778, time stamp: 0x61943c4d
Exception code: 0xc0000602
Fault offset: 0x00000000002224df
Faulting process id: 0x24dc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8ad3e04f2687c
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
Report Id: ce9cb06f-6fd4-4063-9d0f-6168f92dbed8
Faulting package full name: MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_1000.22000.856.0_x64__cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: CortanaUI
```

Any help anyone can provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant.. but probably is.  Are you running StarDock?  If so, doesn't this make it a whole new game?

Comment: I wasn't running StarDock before, but I actually purchased it after making this post.  So far, it's giving me a workable solution to the problems I've been having.
I had to restart search services, too.

Comment: I am glad that you found a good workaround.  StarDock makes cool stuff.